# how to increase the processing speed?

Tags: python-3.x, pytesser

I am working on a small project that is reading text from images. It is taking almost 10 hrs for 20k images now, running on Ubuntu 14.0
Below is a part of the code that is taking quite a lot of time. Please advice /help in increasing the speed or how to use multiprocessing for the below mentioned code?

Regards,
Shri

Code:

```
row = 1
for f1 in files3:
    if f1.lower().endswith( ('.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg') ):
        try:
            image_path1 = files_dir3 + '/' + f1
            txt = pytesseract.image_to_string( Image.open( image_path1 ) )
            print (txt)
            if txt != '':
                print ('0')
                worksheet4.write( row, 1, '0' )
                worksheet4.write( row, 2, txt )
                worksheet4.write( row, 0, image_path1 )
            else:
                worksheet4.write( row, 1, '1' )
                worksheet4.write( row, 2, 'No Text On Image' )
                worksheet4.write( row, 0, image_path1 )
                image_path3 = files_dir3 + '/' + f1
                img = cv2.imread( image_path3 )
                mask = np.zeros( img.shape[:2], np.uint8 )
                bgdModel = np.zeros( (1, 65), np.float64 )
                fgdModel = np.zeros( (1, 65), np.float64 )
                rect = (50, 50, 450, 290)
                cv2.grabCut( img, mask, rect, bgdModel, fgdModel, 5, cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT )
                mask2 = np.where( (mask == 2) | (mask == 0), 0, 1 ).astype( 'uint8' )
                img = img * mask2[:, :, np.newaxis]
                # plt.imshow(img),plt.colorbar(),plt.show()
                cv2.imwrite( os.path.join( files_dir1, f1 ), img )
                print ("Image copied: " + f1)
                if f2.lower().endswith( ('.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg') ):
                    # image_path1 = files_dir + '\\' + f
                    image_path2 = files_dir1 + '/' + f2
                    print (f2)
                    txt = pytesseract.image_to_string( Image.open( image_path2 ) )
                    print (txt)
                    if txt != '':
                        print ('0')
                        worksheet4.write( row, 1, '0' )
                        worksheet4.write( row, 2, txt )
                        worksheet4.write( row, 0, image_path2 )
                    else:
                        print ('1')
                        worksheet4.write( row, 1, '1' )
                        worksheet4.write( row, 2, 'No Text On Image' )
                        worksheet4.write( row, 0, image_path2 )
        except:
            print ("Moving On")
    row += 1
```

Comment: Where are the profiler results?

Comment: I didnt quite understand. Is it the converted images or the actual text detected on the image saved?